# Google Sheets - How to count the occurrence of each day of the week if they are not public holidays?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-dates, google-sheets-custom-function

I would like to count the occurrence of each day of the week in a month if they are not national holidays.

In more details, I would like to know how many Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays, Thursdays, and Fridays a person has to work in a given month because every day has different business hours and their salary is based on that.

So far I am using the following custom function:

```
function occurrenceOfSpecificDay(dayName, monthName, year) {
  // set names
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", 
    "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", 
    "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saterday"
  ];

  // change string to index of array
  var day = dayNames.indexOf(dayName);
  var month = monthNames.indexOf(monthName)+1;

  // determine the number of days in month
  var daysinMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

  // set counter
  var sumDays=0;

  // iterate over the days and compare to day
  for(var i=1; i<=daysinMonth; i++) {
    var checkDay = new Date(year, month-1, parseInt(i)).getDay();    
    if(day === checkDay ) {
      sumDays ++;
    }
  }

  // show amount of day names in month
  return sumDays;
}
```

With this script, I can return how many Mondays are in September 2019 by inserting `=occurrenceOfSpecificDay("Monday", "September", 2019)` into a cell, but I do not want to count the day if it is a holiday.

I would like to extend the following condition with an extra argument that returns false if the given day is a Danish holiday:

```
if(day === checkDay ){
    sumDays ++;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `NETWORKDAYS.INTL' (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3295902)

Comment: I was not, but now I am! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tedinoz guided me to a different approach: instead of the custom function, I ended up using NETWORKDAYS.INTL the following way:

- **Mondays:** `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL("8/1/2019",eomonth("8/1/2019", 0), "0111111")`
- **Tuesdays:** `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL("8/1/2019",eomonth("8/1/2019", 0), "1011111")`
- **Wednesdays:** `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL("8/1/2019",eomonth("8/1/2019", 0), "1101111")`
- **Thursdays:** `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL("8/1/2019",eomonth("8/1/2019", 0), "1110111")`
- **Fridays:** `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL("8/1/2019",eomonth("8/1/2019", 0), "1111011")`

---

### Explanation

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3295902), the 3rd parameter of `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` is a 7-character-long sequence of "1"-s and "0"-s, representing the days of the week (the first character is Monday, the next is Tuesday, etc.) where the "1" means "weekend" and the "0" means "weekday".

Since `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` only counts workdays, it could be used to count specific days by setting the characters representing the other days to "0". Meaning, `0100000` will only count Tuesdays (only if they are not holidays) because the rest of the days are defined as weekends.